# "Merging" Data or "Setting" Data, MediatorLiveData

Tags: java, android-livedata, mediatorlivedata

The docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) talk about merging data... but the function is clearly setting it.

When I think about "merging", I think about something like .add() or .put(), or .set(X x, Y y),.. that I can have 2 objects bundled in one, or a list of obejcts, or an array of objects.

but the functions says .setValue(), and the docs say merge

[image]

And the logs are giving me the impression that the first 2 setValue()'s are being completely ignored:

[image]

So instead of being:

```
   ViewModel: onChnaged: [Folder1, Folder2, Folder3]
   Fragment: onChanged: Folder1 ...etc
   ViewModel: onChanged: []
   Fragment: onChanged:
   ViewModel: onChanged: [Quantity1, Quantity2, Quantity3]
   Fragment: onChanged: Quantity1 ...etc
```

Only the first .setValue(folders) are showing up on the Fragment, which I guess is just because it is taking the longest among the 3 queries to be resolved.

[image: The MediatorLiveData]

....

[image]

So if I'm mistaken about my concept of merge, I'd need to do a LiveData/MutableLiveData<List<?>> with Diff.Util inside it to manage incoming lists or individual objects and also a semaphore to handle asynchronous times(? maybe?).. and an .add() and .replace() functions accordingly, etc..., but then I could use any LiveData, and not a MediatorLiveData<>.

Is there something I could use?

What am I missing?

What's worst, if MediatorLiveData does what I think it does, its really not that difficult to connect multiple LiveDatas to a single observer while handling its lifecycle properly ... whats the point.

I see some Kotlin examples using .combine(data1, data2) but that function doesn't even exist.

Comment: I will try to understand your questions, but just to quickly clarify ".combine(data1, data2)" is a kotlin extension that was created in the code you were looking it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in kotlin, hopefully you can understand or someone can translate to java. I have this extension that combine exactly 3 sources of livedata into a object.

Extension:

```
fun <T, A, B, C> LiveData<A>.combineAndCompute3(
    other1: LiveData<B>,
    other2: LiveData<C>,
    onChange: (A, B?, C?) -> T
): LiveData<T> {

    var source0emitted = false
    var source1emitted = false
    var source2emitted = false

    val result = MediatorLiveData<T>()

    val mergeF = {
        val source0Value = this.value
        val source1Value = other1.value
        val source2Value = other2.value

        if (source0emitted && source1emitted && source2emitted) {
            result.value = onChange.invoke(source0Value!!, source1Value, source2Value)
        }
    }

    result.addSource(this) { source0emitted = true; mergeF.invoke() }
    result.addSource(other1) { source1emitted = true; mergeF.invoke() }
    result.addSource(other2) { source2emitted = true; mergeF.invoke() }

    return result
}
```

and in my viewmodel I have like this:

```
    private val _id = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    private val id = _id.distinctUntilChanged()

    private val _name = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    private val name = _name.distinctUntilChanged()

    private val _load = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private val load = _load.distinctUntilChanged()


    private val detailLoad = id.combineAndCompute3(name, load) {
        A, B, C -> DetailLoad(A, B, C)
    }
```

DetailLoad is a regular data class that A is a integer, B is a String, C is a boolean, and I postValue into my mutablelivedatas in a pretty standard way.

Comment: This looks good, I'm in awe of how Kotlin works... I don't know enough about Java, but this:

onChange.invoke(source0Value!!, source1Value, source2Value)

I would've created my own observer with vargArgs parameters to achieve it, I didnt knew you could just pass whatever you want there(is that a property of ), and very interesting how the onChanged is "invoked"

Comment: also I dont fully understand how but the onChange is getting triggered with every onChange of its source, I did something similar in java once but instead I used a .wait() for the answer of other sources.
Thanks for your answer, the problem with this solution is that I need the answers not in"parallel" but in a List so that I can submit them on an adapter.

Comment: I mean its useful, you gave me a lot of ideas...

ALso is the code a class? or a function? Also why are you not needed to define its wildcards when called?

Comment: the onChange is getting triggered everytime a source changes. In fact, in my code, it is emiting a result only when all 3 sources have emitted something. What really controls the flow is the "result.addSource() {}" invoking the "mergeF.invoke()" that invokes onChange when my if statement passes.
I think it is doable to convert this code to answer a list.

Comment: this code is an extension, it is a function. You mean the "id", this function will work from any livedata, as it is LiveData<T>.combineAndCompute(), so I can start from any LiveData, and it will use itself (the livedata) as the T.
I dont know if got ur question correctly.